# When I fetch data from API showing StatusCode 403 (Failed to load post) - Flutter.?

Tags: flutter, dart

e.g.: details about the questions

When I want to fetch multiple objects from an array showing status code 403 (Failed to load post), and API having a header key I have implemented it also, but showing failed to load post status code 403.

```
 {
    "status": 1,
    "msg": "7 banners found",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "14",
            "image": "https://www.sofikart.com/admin/upload/app_banner/1635945056.jpeg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "product_id": "81",
            "url": null,
            "status": "Active",
            "ordering": "0",
            "updated": "2021-11-03 06:10:56"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "image": "https://www.sofikart.com/admin/upload/app_banner/1642082634.jpeg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "product_id": "111",
            "url": null,
            "status": "Active",
            "ordering": "1",
            "updated": "2021-10-28 04:53:26"
        }
    ]
}
```

Controller

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:fm_sidharth/model/post.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

final String url = 'https://www.sofikart.com/MobileApi/banners';

Future<List<Post>> fetchPost() async {

  final response = await http.get(
    url, headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'SOFIKART-*2021#',},);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON.
    final result = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Post> posts =
    result.map<Post>((model) => new Post.fromJson(model)).toList();
    return posts;

  } else {
    // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}

Future<String> saveNetworkImageToPhoto(String url, String title,
    {bool useCache: true}) async {
  var data = await getNetworkImageData(url, useCache: useCache);
  var filePath = await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: data, title: title);
  return filePath;
}

class ImagePickerSaver {
  static saveFile({fileData, String title}) {}
}

getNetworkImageData(String url, {booluseCache, bool
useCache}) {
}
```

Model

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final welcome = welcomeFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Post welcomeFromJson(String str) => Post.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String welcomeToJson(Post data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Post {
  Post({
    this.status,
    this.msg,
    this.data,
  });

  int status;
  String msg;
  List<Datum> data;

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Post(
    status: json["status"],
    msg: json["msg"],
    data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
  );

  String get catId => null;

  get image => null;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "status": status,
    "msg": msg,
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.catId,
    this.productId,
    this.url,
    this.status,
    this.ordering,
    this.updated,
  });

  String id;
  String image;
  String catId;
  String productId;
  dynamic url;
  String status;
  String ordering;
  DateTime updated;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    id: json["id"],
    image: json["image"],
    catId: json["cat_id"],
    productId: json["product_id"],
    url: json["url"],
    status: json["status"],
    ordering: json["ordering"],
    updated: DateTime.parse(json["updated"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "image": image,
    "cat_id": catId,
    "product_id": productId,
    "url": url,
    "status": status,
    "ordering": ordering,
    "updated": updated.toIso8601String(),
  };
}
```

Home

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fm_sidharth/Controller/postController.dart';
import 'package:fm_sidharth/model/post.dart';
import 'package:fm_sidharth/page/postdetails.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future<List<Post>> posts;
  _HomePageState() {
    posts = fetchPost();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
        future: posts,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                PostDetails(snapshot.data[index])),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              snapshot.data[index].catId,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 22,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                            image: snapshot.data[index].image,
                            placeholder: 'assets/images/noimage.png',
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                                onPressed: () {

                                },
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.save),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  saveNetworkImageToPhoto(
                                      snapshot.data[index].image,snapshot.data[index].catId).then((value){

                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }

          // By default, show a loading spinner.
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You will get the 403 forbidden error when you visit an empty website directory or a specific page that has not permitted to view or show to the public.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP 403 means that the access to the requested resource is forbidden. The server understood the request, but it is unable to  fulfill it. Are you sure you sent the required(and correct) credentials to the server?